# What special about this subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Given $V=\mathbb{R^n}$ (vector space of all $n×1$ column vectors over $\mathbb{R}$) and $W=\{[x_1, x_2,...,x_n]^t\in \mathbb{R^n} : a_1x_1+...+a_nx_n≥0\}$

where $a_1,...,a_n\in\mathbb{R}$.

Then clearly zero vector is in $W$ and for $k\in\mathbb{R}$ , $X,Y\in W$ we have $X+Y, kX\in W$ and hence $W$ is subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ (**is am I correct?**)
**If yes** then what does above subspace represent? Is there is something special about this subspace?

Comment: What happens for $k<0$?

Comment: This is not actually a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$, but it represents all points on or one particular side of the hyperplane $a_1x_1 + \cdots + a_n x_n = 0$. This is known as a (closed) [half-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-space_(geometry)).

Comment: Sir question is edited now. Please check  I think for  $k<0$ too it is subspace. Because we can always find scalars $a_1,...,a_n$ in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Yes they are not fixed

Comment: If they are not fixed, then your set would be the set of all $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)^{T}\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that there exist $a_1,\ldots, a_n\in \mathbb{R}$ with $a_1 x_1 + \cdots  + a_n x_n \ge 0$. But actually any $(x_1,\ldots, x_n)^{T}\in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ satisfies this (you could always choose the $a_i$ to all be $0$, for example).

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth  sir. Yes that's why I thought it must be subspace. Is my guess is correct? Is $W=\mathbb{R^n}$

Comment: If the $a_i$ are not fixed, then yes, $W = \mathbb{R}^{n}$. But as the question is written, it means that they are fixed beforehand.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth sir, if they are not fixed then?

Comment: If they are not fixed, then $W$ would just be $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** If $\cdot$ denotes the usual dot product on $\Bbb R^n$, we can rewrite
$$W = \{{\bf x} \in \Bbb R^n : {\bf x} \cdot {\bf a} \geq 0\} ,$$
where ${\bf a} := \pmatrix{a_1&\cdots&a_n}^\top$. So, what is the geometric meaning of ${\bf x} \cdot {\bf a} \geq 0$?

Comment: Sir please elaborate and isn't the vector $X$ must be column vector in your written subspace $W$? and in question given that $a_1,...,a_n$ are scalars.i don't know they are fixed or not.

Comment: Can you specify what you would like elaborated? I don't understand your first question. It's true that $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ are scalars; the observation in my answer is that (1) they can also be viewed as the components of a vector in $\Bbb R^n$ and (2) if we do so we can write $W$ compactly in terms of the dot product. On the other hand, you probably already know a geometric interpretation of the dot product.

Comment: Thank you so much sir. Is $W$  subspace? I am sure yes. geometric meaning of $x•a≥0$ means cosine of angle between the between the vectors is positive? am I correct sir?

Comment: **Hint** If ${\bf a} \neq 0$, is ${\bf a} \in W$? Is $-{\bf a} \in W$? What happens if ${\bf a} = {\bf 0}$? And that's almost correct: We have ${\bf x} \cdot {\bf a} = |{\bf x}||{\bf x}| \cos \theta$, where $\theta \in [0, \pi]$ is the angle between the vectors, so the condition is that $\cos \theta$ is nonnegative (i.e., positive or zero).

Comment: Sir, if $a≠0$ then as $a•a≥0$ we must have $a\in W$ similarly as $(-a)•(-a)≥0$ we must have $(-a)\in W$ and if $a=0$ then for each vector $x\in \mathbb{R^n}$ we have $x•a=0$ and hence I think when $a=0$ we must have $W=\mathbb{R^n}$. But this doesn't prove whether $W$ is subspace or not in the case when $a≠0$.Please help.

Comment: sir, let $X=(x_1...x_n)^t$ and $Y=(y_1...y_n)^t$ are in $W$ then $X•a≥0$ and $Y•a≥0$ now $(X+Y)•a= (x_1+y_1...x_n+y_n)^t•(a_1...a_n)^t= x_1•a_1+...+x_n•a_n + y_1•a_1+...+y_n•a_n ≥0$ and so that $X,Y\in W$ and we can also prove for $k\in \mathbb{R}$, $kX\in W$ and hence $W$ must be subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Please tell me if am incorrect.

Comment: The test for whether $-{\bf a} in W$ is, by our formula, $-{\bf a} \cdot {\bf a} \geq 0$. Also, how can you prove for $X \in W, k \in \Bbb R$ that $k X \in W$?

Comment: Sir, yes for each $k\in\mathbb{R}$ , $kX ∉W$. Hence $W$ is not a subspace. Sir is $W$ is subspace only when $a=(0...0)^t$ ? Or for some other $a$ too?

Comment: The test in my previous comment shows that it is a subspace only for $a_1 = 0, \ldots, a_n = 0$.

Comment: Sir Thank you so much for giving me your valuable time and Sorry for any trouble from my side.

Comment: You're welcome, I hope you found my comments helpful.